# Programming Design Architecture Q

Tags: architecture

I am architecting a WebAPI. In that WebAPI, I have the following structure using DI (IoC):

```
Controllers -> Services -> Repositorys  -> EF : DB.
```

Now when a request can use multiple services what is best practice:

```
Controller -> ServiceOne/ServiceTwo -> Repositories
```

Where ServiceTwo is instantiated in ServiceOne's constructor (or) ServiceTwo and ServiceOne or both instantiated in Controller constructor.

I am trying to achieve separation of concerns and stuck on this implementation. I am also trying to accomplish good organization of code and less code duplication.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can inject serviceOne and Two into controller. Also you can inject ServiceTwo into serviceOne also. Ultimately you will achieve the separation of concerns.

Comment: Out of the two, what would you say is best practice?

Comment: I'd say injecting serviceTwo into serviceOne would be good approach as controller does not have to deal with a lot of if elses to decide which service to go with. let the service layer followup with other services and conglomerate the data and return it to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting it as answer in addition to the comment as it exceed the lenght.

I'd say injecting serviceTwo into serviceOne would be good approach as controller does not have to deal with a lot of if elses to decide which service to go with. let the service layer followup with other services and conglomerate the data and return it to the controller.

**If you have services injected within the services**

Pros:

1. Service layers tend to have transactions on each of the
   method, if you are dealing with a lot of calls to several different
   services then they all go under one big transaction.
2. Controller just delegates the request to a service where all the business logic happens, you can ensure separation of concerns.
3. We can reuse the services in several different combinations if possible.
4. Error handling would become easier
5. Controller can concentrate more on how and what type of data to return etc,

Cons:

1. You cannot create a child transaction within a transaction if using spring transactionals

**If you have services injected into the controller**

Pros:

1. You can create a new transaction for each service. Ofcoz this
   service cannot create a child transaction boundary.

Cons:

1. If you have a lot of services within the controller then each
   service call falls in as a different transaction, so, if one fails
   the other service calls are not rolledback.
2. Controller is the one which is clubbing/merging several services to get the task done.
3. Re-usability will be reduced